# Using google cloud endpoint for cron job

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-endpoints

As per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron?hl=en#Java_calling_google_cloud_endpoints You cannot reference a cloud endpoint directly with a cron job. You must reference a jsp or other file which then calls the endpoint. Ive done some tinkering in jsp, but I cannot get anythign referencing my endpoint to compile and nothing useful shows in the errorlog to help me trace.

so, if I have endpoint

myEp

and I want a cron to work calling 
`myEp("x","y",z");`

how can I achieve this in java using an appengine backend? Any code to help would be a lifesaver. I understand how to build the cron xml file, it is the page it references that has me lost.

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: I did not. Thankfully the project flopped. I still want to know though

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is less than helpful. Anyone who read the intro to endpoints documentation knows that. The question is about how to achieve the result, which I am aware is possible.

Comment: Sorry that is why i deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Probably late, but this, will may be help someone : [Episode 9: Using the Cron Service to run scheduled tasks](http://rominirani.com/2009/11/16/episode-9-using-the-cron-service-to-run-scheduled-tasks/)